# How do I show an activity indicator in swiftUI while my CoreData is being fetched?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

When I create or update a CoreData entry in swiftUI it takes a moment for my app to update. During this time I'd like provide some visual feedback in the form of an Activity Indicator. Following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@tianna_lewis05/cracking-swiftui-implementing-uiactivityindicator-3e1402d5677f) I can get the loading view to appear but how do I get it to disappear once it's Fetched my updated entries?

**Content View**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {

    @FetchRequest(entity: DiaryItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \DiaryItem.createdAt, ascending: false),
    ]) var diaryItems : FetchedResults<DiaryItem>

    var body: some View {
        LoadingView(isShowing: .constant(true)) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(self.diaryItems) { diaryItem in
                    DiaryItemView(
                        title: diaryItem.title!,
                        createdAt: "\(diaryItem.createdAt!)",
                        diaryItem: diaryItem
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ActivityIndicator: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        return UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) {
        isAnimating ? uiView.startAnimating() : uiView.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

**Loading View**

```
struct LoadingView<Content>: View where Content: View {

    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {

                self.content()
                    .disabled(self.isShowing)
                    .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 3 : 0)

                VStack {
                    ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2,
                       height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                .background(Color.secondary.colorInvert())
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you have found your answer for this... in your code, the ActivityIndicator(isAnimating:) is being called with a constant value of true.

If you change that to use the LoadingView.isShowing (which appears to be what you intended) when that binding (which is also set to a constant value of true) changes from true to false the activity indicator will be hidden.

Ex:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLoading = true //Added to track when loading is happening

    @FetchRequest(entity: DiaryItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \DiaryItem.createdAt, ascending: false),
    ]) var diaryItems : FetchedResults<DiaryItem>

    var body: some View {
        LoadingView(isShowing: $isLoading) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In LoadingView:

```
ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: $isShowing, style: .large)
```